# Aerogel to filter virus particles

Tags: materials

With the hype around COVID-19 DIY technology, everyone seems to circle around the same concepts.

I'm trying to think outside the box and I was wondering:

Is it possible to controllably create an aerogel that is extremely permeable and also captures virus particles?

This is in essence a Yes/No question, but I'd love to get some mid-lengthy answers.

I think it's a very interesting concept.

Comment: Aerogel does have pore smaller than viruses but unless we have a way to mass produce aerogel at low cost, it will not be economically efficient to use it. It is soluble in water so all filter must be single use only. Also, viruses do not transmit in air just by themselves, instead they stick to mucus droplets which traditional mask fabric can block them, so there isn't much significance in effectiveness in using aerogel over mask fabric.